# Rails How to get Javascript working without webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm running `rails 6.1.7.6` and `ruby 3.1.1`

I'm set up a new rails app on heroku.  I tried for two days to get webpack working but I couldn't.  I followed many threads, but it kept saying I needed to install the webpack-cli.  I had it installed, but the app just wouldn't see it.  So I'm trying to get javascript working without it.  I followed a couple of threads that said to do these steps:

```
# app/assets/config/manifest.js

//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_directory ../javascript .js   <-- I added this line
```

I created an application.js in `app/assets/javascript/`

```
# app/assets/javascript/application.js

//
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require activestorage

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("What the What?");
});
```

```
# views/layouts/application.html.erb
# this next line was:

 <%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

The `javascript_include_tag` causes an error. I read in a thread stating to change this to:

```
<%= javascript_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

```
# Gemfile:

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0.4'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
```

But my views do not see my `application.js`.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?